# $checkLike = $user->places->contains($placeId); keeps returning false even though by my calculations it should be returning true

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

This `$checkLike = $user->places->contains($placeId);` is meant to check if the user has liked the sight with placeId, however, it keep returning false even though there's a record inside the database.

I have 3 tables like this:

```
Table: Users
Columns: id, username, password

Table: Places
Columns: id, place_id

Table: Place_User
Columns: id, user_id, place_id
```

and currently I have 1 record in each table like this:

```
   Users             Place_User          Places

6, Admin, Admin
                      1, 6, 15
                                    15, b4b8adfb46dfbabdf864b
```

So I assumed `$checkLike = $user->places->contains($placeId);` would return true when there's already a record. Sadly that's not the case.

My models:

```
class User extends \Eloquent implements Authenticatable
{
    use AuthenticableTrait;

    public function places(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Place');
    }
}
```

And

```
class Place extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

Comment: `dump($user->places)` might give you some information.

Comment: So I can't exactly dump($user->places) because my front-end is separated from the back-end and written in Vue.js so adding dump($user->places) does nothing. However, if I send a response to the front-end that contains $user->places, it shows that its an array that contains 1 object that contains an id, place_id and pivot fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `->contains` method would only work if your `$placeId` is set to the `id` of a place, and not the `place_id` of `App\Place`.

Take the following as an example:

```
$placeId = 15;
$user->places->contains($placeId); // true
```

However, the following would return false because it's referencing to `place_id` attribute:

```
$placeId = 'b4b8adfb46dfbabdf864b';
$user->places->contains($placeId); // false
```

To achieve the above, you have to pass a callable and compare the right attribute:

```
$placeId = 'b4b8adfb46dfbabdf864b';
$user->places->contains(function ($place) use ($placeId) {
    return $place->place_id == $placeId;
});
```

Comment: The question doesn't say what the content of `$placeId` is, but it implies that it's 15.

Comment: Yeah this might be the problem, the placeId that I'm using is not the primary key id of the table but the place_id. I'm gonna try it out right now and see what happens.

Comment: Yep, that was the issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @miken32 If the content of `$placeId` was `15`, it would return `true`.